# Logo Degrading Old IE and Safari Windows - Advice Needed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

cambrianvacation.co.uk/safeside

The Safeside logo is saved as PNG-24 in Photoshop CS6, but there is some degradation in old versions of IE and Safari / Windows.

The size of the image in Photoshop is close to the actual size on the site, th quality I've saved it at is high, it needs to be a PNG as I need the transparency.

Does anyone know why it degrades in these browsers, everywhere lese it looks great.

Ant:-)

Comment: Specifically **what versions** of browsers? "Old" is not enough information. PNG24 is not supported in IE6 and only partially supported in IE7. PNG24 should be okay in Safari. However, the logo is a background image, that may present problems with older Safari versions.

Comment: Yeah IE7, IE8 is fine, IE6 I'm not supporting. It must be degrading in IE7 because of the partial support for PNG24, I'll change the format to standard PNG. What's the deal with Safari and background-images? It's fine on my friends Mac by the way, just Windows 5.17

Answer (score 1):

*(...that's some complicated HTML to get to the image...)*

So, that image is slightly larger than the size it displays on the page: it's  a 298x237 image in a 240x200 `img` tag. Modern browsers are good at scaling images down, older browsers used to be a bit rubbish at resizing images (including IE as recent as IE8). Sharp edges - like those in a logo, but unlike most photos - would look scuffy.

Unless it's essential to a responsive design or something similar, it's a good idea to use the exact size of image that will be displayed on the page: i.e. a 240x200 png in a 240x200 `img` tag.

Especially for a logo where you want to know it looks exactly right.

Comment: Cool will do, should sort it. The complex html I'm building it in Drupal (say no more!!!)Thanks guys, great forum quick friendly response:-)

Comment: Unfortunately resizing the image down as close to the actual output and changing the format to a PNG-8 has made no difference in Safari 5.17 in Windows, but it looks a lot better in IE7, still a bit jagged. Is there some issue with Safari 5.1.7 and rendering graphics?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe Apple quit supporting Safari on Windows because of weird problematic issues they didn't want to devote time to fixing. The user base for that platform was just too low to care I think.

Comment: Thanks I am actually going to quote that (sorry) how else can I explain it to the client......:-)